# Menu Driven Logic Error Causing Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, loops, menu, infinite-loop

all.

This is my first post. I appreciate all help I can get with this.

I have tested the functions. They work fine. The purpose of the program is as follows:

1) User inputs a string

2) Menu is displayed

3) User selects choice of

a) count vowels
b) count consonants
c) count string letters
d) input another string
e) quit

4) The menu keeps cycling until the user selects E

I know it is embarrassing I'm having loop issues while I'm now working with pointers, but it is what it is.

Thank you for you patience with my simple mind!

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>//Case conversion
using namespace std;

//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
int countVowels(char *);
int countCons(char *);
int countAlpha(char *);

//FUNCTION MAIN

int main()
{
const int SIZE = 50;
char inputString[SIZE];

char a,b,c,d,e,f;
int choice,
    totalVowels,
    totalConsonants,
    totalLetters;

//Get the string from the user
cout << "Please enter a string consisting of 49 characters or less. ";
cin.getline(inputString, SIZE);


do{

    cout << "\nPlease make a selection from the menu:\n"
         << "a) Counts the vowels\n"
         << "b) Counts the connsonants\n"
         << "c) Counts the string\n"
         << "d) Enter another string\n"
         << "e) Quit" << endl;

    cout << "\nChoice is: ";
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice < 'a' || choice > 'e')
        {
            cout << "Invalid choice. Try again ";
            cin >> choice;
        }           
    //Call a function to count the vowels

    if (choice == tolower('a'))
    {
        totalVowels = countVowels(inputString);
        cout << "\n" << totalVowels << " Vowels" << endl;

    }


    //Call a function to count the vowels

    else if (choice == tolower('b'))
    {
        totalConsonants = countCons(inputString);
        cout << "\n" << totalConsonants << " Consonants" << endl;
    }

    //Call a function to count all letters

    else if (choice == tolower('c'))
    {
        totalLetters = countAlpha(inputString);
        cout << "\n" << totalLetters << " Letters" << endl;

    }

    //Write a new string

    else if (choice == tolower('d'))
    {
        cout << "Please enter a string consisting of 49 characters or less. 
";
        cin.getline(inputString, SIZE);

    }

} while (choice != tolower('e'));


return 0;
}

//FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

////Count the Vowels


 int countVowels(char* strPtr)
  {
    int vowelCount = 0; //Each time a vowel is counted

    while (*strPtr != '\0')
    {
        if (tolower(*strPtr) == 'a'
            ||tolower(*strPtr) == 'e' 
            ||tolower(*strPtr)== 'i' 
            ||tolower(*strPtr) == 'o' 
            ||tolower(*strPtr)== 'u')

            {
                vowelCount++;
            }
        strPtr++;
    }

    return vowelCount;
}

//Count the Consonants


int countCons(char* strPtr)
{

  int conCount = 0; //Each time a consonant  is counted

    while (*strPtr != '\0')
    {
        if (tolower(*strPtr) != 'a' 
            && tolower(*strPtr) != 'e' 
            && tolower(*strPtr) != 'i' 
            && tolower(*strPtr) != 'o'          //Clean this up
            && tolower(*strPtr) != 'u'          // See section 10.1 for more 
            && tolower(*strPtr) != ' '
            && tolower(*strPtr) != ','
            && tolower(*strPtr) != '?'
            && tolower(*strPtr) != '.'
            && tolower(*strPtr) != '!')

            {
                conCount++;
            }
        strPtr++;
    }

    return conCount;
}

//Count the Letters in the string


int countAlpha(char* strPtr)
{

  int alphaCount = 0;

    while (*strPtr != '\0')
    {
        if (isalpha (tolower(*strPtr))) 
        {
            alphaCount++;
        }
        strPtr++;
}

return alphaCount;  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please clarify what exactly the problem is (e.g. observed behavior is different from expected, and how different) and/or what is your question explicitly in the message body? (click "edit")

Comment: @greid Declare choice as having the type char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `choice` is declared as having the type `int`. So when you enter a character an error of the input stream occurred. Any other input in this case is ignored.

Declare the variable like

```
char choice;
```

Take into account that these variables

```
char a,b,c,d,e,f;
```

are not used in the program.

And conditions like this

```
choice == tolower('a')
```

does not make a great sense.

Just write

```
choice == 'a'
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much for your input.